# For which $p$ is a number a square in $\mathbb{Q}_p$?

Tags: number-theory, p-adic-number-theory

I have some numbers $r \in \{-1, 2, \frac{4}{5}, \ldots\}$ and have to find those primes $p$ for which $r$ is a square in $\mathbb{Q}_p$, i. e. is a solution of the equation $X^2 = r$ in $\mathbb{Q}_p$.

How do I do that?

I first thought that I would just try to use Hensel's lemma, but this is an exercise in a chapter about the Hilbert symbol...

Comment: The first step of using Hensel's lemma is finding out whether the equation has a solution $\bmod p$ (more or less), and you can do that using quadratic reciprocity.

Comment: See http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/551562/properties-of-squares-in-mathbb-q-p.

Comment: @QiaochuYuan: I think I found out what it has to do with the Hilbert symbol, it's simply that $a\in\mathbb{Q}_p$ is a square if for all $b\in\mathbb{Q}_p$ the Hibert symbol $\left(\frac{a, b}{p}\right) =1$.

Comment: Yes, but Hensel is what you want.