# what is $\mathbb{Q}_p^\times/\mathbb{Q}_p^{\times^2}$ called?

Tags: number-theory, p-adic-number-theory

I have to do a presentation about $p$-adic numbers and I don't know what to call $\mathbb{Q}_p^\times/\mathbb{Q}_p^{\times^2}$. Can you help me, please?

Thank you!

Comment: The units of $\mathbb Q_p$ modulo the squares ?

Comment: Just "quotient group". For more information see for example [this post](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/551562/properties-of-squares-in-mathbb-q-p/551582#551582). Have you looked into Serre's book?

Comment: Well $\mathbb{Q}_p^\times$ is the field of p-adic numbers except zero, and $\mathbb{Q}_p^{\times^2}$ are those who are squares. In Serre's book it's just used as I have written, so I'am not very sure @DietrichBurde . Just quotient group?

Comment: If Serre calls it quotient group, then why don't you want to call it like this? You can also call it the "Klein $4$- group" for $p>2$, at least it is isomorphic to it.

Comment: @DietrichBurde well, I want to talk about $\mathbb{Q}_p^\times/\mathbb{Q}_p^{\times^2}$ and $\mathbb{Q}_2^\times/\mathbb{Q}_2^{\times^2}$... So I don't want to say the quotient group and the quotient group.

Comment: Okey, Thank you!!  @DietrichBurde

Comment: @DietrichBurde why did you delete the comment?

Comment: Because you were saying it is OK (sorry, "Okey" :) )

Answer (score 2):

For an arbitrary field $K$, a name used for $K^\times/(K^\times)^2$ is the group of "square classes" (understood not to include $0$).  It is a bit more specific than the more general term "quotient group".  For example, $\mathbf R$ has two square classes while $\mathbf Q_p$ has four square classes when $p \not= 2$ and eight square classes when $p = 2$. The field $\mathbf Q$ has infinitely many square classes.